# What does "| arg" mean in a variable definition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I notice some syntax I'm not familiar with:

```
name: int|None
```

Can you explain please what does it mean?

It is a nullable int?

Can I do it with non-related types?
N-types?

Does it have restrictions?

How should I use it?

Comment: This is identical to `typing.Optional[int]`. Combining types with `|` creates a union, saying either of those types is allowed. In this case, `int` is one of the allowed types, and `None` is the other.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `int | None` is a type hint in Python indicating that a variable can be an `int` or `None`. It's used for type checking and can be applied to any types, not just related ones, without restrictions.

Example:

```py
def process(value: int | None) -> None:
    if value is not None:
        print(value)
    else:
        print("No value")

# This function accepts an int, None, or a string.
def multi_type(arg: int | str | None) -> None:
    print(arg)
```